# Block user when failed to login more than 3 times

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, session

I am new in Codeigniter and I want to create a login that can block a user when it has failed to log in more than 3 times.
this is my controller

**User.php**

```
 public function login_proses() {

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[45]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

      if($this->m_user->m_cek_mail()->num_rows()==1) {

        $db=$this->m_user->m_cek_mail()->row();
        if(hash_verified($this->input->post('password'),$db->password)) {

                $data_login=array('is_login'=>TRUE,
                        'email'  =>$db->email,
                        'nama'   =>$db->nama);

                $this->session->set_userdata($data_login);
                redirect('user/dashboard','refresh');

                    } else {

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', 'Login gagal: password salah!');
                    redirect('/','refresh');
                    }

      } else { // jika email tidak terdaftar!

      $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', 'Login gagal: email salah!');
      redirect('/','refresh');

      }

} else { 

    $this->load->view('user/form_login');
}

 }
```

And this is the login form at the view

**form_login.php**

```
<div class="login">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Login To Your Start</h4>
<p style="color: red; text-align: center;"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('pesan'); ?></p>
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/login_proses"  method="post">
  <label>email or username</label>
  <input type="email" name="email"class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
  <label>password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"><br>
  <button type="submit" value="Login" class="btnSubmit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Best way in my opinion is to keep track of how many attempts a specific email or IP has made to login by making a new table in your SQL database. When the total attempts exceeds 3 times, you tell them that they have been blocked for to many attempts. Also. Make sure to timestamp it so that you can allow them to try again later.

Comment: can you give me an example for the code or some web page for reference

Comment: Unlike Niels recommend you don't really need a separate table for this, just add a new column (tinyint or smallint) to your usertable which have a default value of 0. Each login attempt you check this value if its already 3, if so you deny a login. If not and the login credentials are invalid you increase this value. If the login credentials are valid reset this value to 0;

Comment: You have to build the logic yourself first. If you are familiar with PHP this should not be that difficult. When a login fails you insert a new row into your new table with the IP of the user or email address and other things like timestamp, date etc. When there are more than 3 rows matching either IP or email address within a certain amount of time you deny the user any more login attempts.

Comment: What CodyKL suggests is an option but the problem with his solution is that you will not stop hackers from attempting a million times if they have a lot of stolen credentials. You would only deny them 3 times if the user in the user database exists. And you might block a legit user that haven't even caused the blockade. My solution would either be based on email address and IP at the same time or use Google recaptcha to annoy users when too many attempts have been made.